# Create New Hook To Call module blocksearch Inside Another Module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to put blocksearch module into a leomegamenu module, my problem is how to do that(that is which files to modify. Can somebody give me pointers to which files to go.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `blocksearch.php`. It is linked to hook `hookDisplaySearch`.

In your `leomegamenu` template files you can add this code:

```
{hook h='displaySearch' mod='blocksearch'}
```